# reading from DataInputStream without knowing the output type 

Tags: java, stream

Say i'm using `DataInputStream` to recieve data, but I don't know if I should use (for example) `readUTF`, `readInt` or `readLong`. Is there a method that tells me what type of data is written on the other side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no mechanism to introspect the stream to find out this information. If you need to do this, then the sender needs to add meta-data to the stream indicating what sort of data is coming next.

For example, the sender can send a `0` byte (which could be a signal for "the next data item is an `int`"), and then send the `int`, then send a `1` byte (the signal for "the next data item is a `long`"), followed by the `long` itself.

The consumer would read off the signals, and know whether to call `readInt` or `readLong`.

Alternatively, you can use `ObjectInput` and `ObjectOutput` instead of `DataInputStream`, which performs the introspection for you (if you use `writeObject()` and `readObject()`).

Answer (score 1):

No. It is all a raw binary data for it. Unless you specify what you expect, it is all the same for it.